# Parsing InputStream into Json object and getting a value

Tags: java, json, rest

## The response json:

```
{
    "filename": "vcops-6.0.0-MPforAWS-1.1-1695068.pak",
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "pak_information",
            "href": "https://<IP>:443/casa/upgrade/cluster/pak/MPforAWS-600/information"
        },
        {
            "rel": "pak_file_information",
            "href": "https://<IP>:443/casa/upgrade/slice/pak/MPforAWS-600/file_information"
        },
        {
            "rel": "pak_cluster_status",
            "href": "https://<IP>:443/casa/upgrade/cluster/pak/MPforAWS-600/status"
        }
    ],
    "pak_id": "MPforAWS-600"
}
```

I am using one helper of the framework we have. Framework returns response as "InputStream".
I want to get "pak_id" from this "InputStream". I tried with `inputStreamObj.toString()` this does not work for me.

The method I am using is:

```
private String getPakId(InputStream uploadResponse) {
    String pakId = null;
    try {
        String responseString = readInputStream(uploadResponse);
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
        pakId = jObj.getString("pak_id").trim();
        Reporter.log("Pak id is=" + pakId, true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Reporter.log("Error in getting pak_id " + e.getMessage(), true);
    }
    return pakId;
}
```

and

```
private String readInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream, "UTF-8"));
    String tmp;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(tmp).append("\n");
    }
    if (sb.length() > 0 && sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) == '\n') {
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: And what is your current code?

Comment: You have to read the String from your InputStream and then parse it using JSON library.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511880/how-to-parse-a-json-input-stream

Comment: JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
pakId = jObj.getString("pak_id").trim();

Comment: The question is duplicate. Try this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47265988/1264496

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the documentation for [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), you'll notice it will not promise you that `toString` will present you the contents of the stream.

If you're not interested in actually streaming the stream (which is reasonable if you expect the response to be small, like it appears to be the case here), it's OK to first get all the bytes from the stream, put them into a `String`, and then parse the `String`.

To get the `String` out of the `InputStream`, I'd recommend `IOUtils.toString` from [apache commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/description.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the `pak_id` value using only the standard library:

```
InputStream is = ...
String line;
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append(line).append(" ");
}
String pakId = text.toString().replaceAll(".*\"pak_id\": \"([^\"]+)\".*", "$1");
```

Comment: What I want to say, I have this response stored in "InputStream" object, and I need to retrieve "pak_id"

Comment: I updated my answer so now you can obtain the `pak_id` value directly from the `InputStream`

Answer (score -1):

Well, better late than never... the following worked for me:

```
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(new InputStreamReader(istream));
JSONObject result;
try {
    result = new JSONObject(tokener);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // Handle me!
}
```