# Retrieve JSON value as inputstream

Tags: java, jackson, gson, json-simple

My JSON will be as follows:

```
{
"id" : "1",
"data" : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
}
```

I am ready to use any JSON Parser. But I want the data element as InputStream.

Could you please me to implement the same in Java?

Comment: Normally, I used to create simple value objects and map the stream to the simple value object. But in this case, the value of  "data " will be more than 10 MB...So i want the "data" as input stream

Answer (score 0):

Use [GSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson) or [JSON](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) from maven Repository it's simple to use and nice , If you need to create test project use JSON library and if you need to use for heavy Json or Parse to Object use GSON library. if you need to write JSON to file that's not about json library , if you need to read json format from input stream in this case both of them can help you.
check this question : [Convert InputStream to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461663/convert-inputstream-to-jsonobject)

Comment: I want the data attribute as an input stream.

Comment: what? you need add binary as value?

Comment: Sorry...It will decode the value...But, my input is not encoded one...So I cant use read binary as a value...

Comment: Show your output @user1862354

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected end of base64-encoded String: base64 variant 'MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS' expects padding (one or more '=' characters) at the end

Comment: the base64 can use in json and I'm using it to send pic but you need to convert base64 with MIME for explain what base64 for it. so if you share String of base64 we can help you.

Comment: As explained above, the customer will send the JSON as plain text, not the Base 64 encoded one.