# InputStream to JSONElement exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to covert InputStream to JSON Element using below code

```
public jsonElement  parsejsonContentFromStream (Inputstream in){
Charset inputCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF-8;
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in, inputCharset);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new  BufferedReader (isr);
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
return parser.parse(bufferedReader);
}
```

Exception

```
Not a JSON object : “\u001f?\b\u000\u000\u0004\u0003uT”
```

Then I tried below code

```
public JsonElement parseJsonContentFromStream(InputStream in) {
InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(in);
logger.info("Encode ="+ ir.getEncoding());
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStream Reader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
JsonReader jr = new JsonReader(isr);
JsonElement je=JsonParser.parseReader(jr).getAsJonObject();
return je;
}
```

Still seeing same error message.

```
Info:Encode = Cp1252
Java.lang.illegalStateException:Not a JSON object : “\u001f?\b\u000\u000\u0004\u0003uT”
```

Pls ignore any syntax error.

Comment: What would you expect? That data is not json. What do you expect the input stream to contain?

Comment: Expected: {“response”:[{“portfolio:”12345”,”id”:”555555”}]}. 

Actual: “\u001f<\b\u0000\u000”

Comment: Evidently, that is not what is actually inside of it. Try just consuming the input stream and outputting it a string to see that this is not the json parsers fault but the data is the problem.

Comment: I tested with SOAPUI. rest service is giving back the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code snippet for the same,

```
public jsonElement  parsejsonContentFromStream (Inputstream in){
Charset inputCharset = StandardCharsets.UTF-8;
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in, inputCharset);
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)parser.parse(isr);
return jsonObject;
}
```

You can also refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461663/convert-inputstream-to-jsonobject) for a detailed discussion on inputStream to Json discussions.